# youtube like offline functionality in android app

Tags: android, video, youtube, offline

I'm working on an android app which can download the **video** from server and store it in **SD card**. and plays it while the app is in **offline** mode. but i want the add one more functionality to my app. now the videos downloaded by app can be played by any video player in the device. But i want to restrict that functionality.so the videos downloaded by my app can only playable by my app(**like youtube app**).

I'm totally new to this functionality .. any ideas and approaches to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: important thing is... how you storing video in your app...

Comment: @kiturk3 now the video will be downloaded and stored in folder(like whatsapp) sd card .. using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"AppName/video.mp4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Vivek Kumar Srivastava: 
If you are working on Api Level-8 then I suggest to use `getExternalFilesDir (String type)`

instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` because there are two benefit using this

-all images and data will be automatically deleted when your application uninstall by user

-images do not visible in the media application (in Gallery).